# How do I sanitize sensitive fields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Some of the fields in my MongoDB documents contain sensitive data, and when I use this data for testing I need to sanitise them.

The data was previously stored in MySQL and I did this with something like `REPEAT('x', LENGTH(fieldName))`.

I would like to keep the length of the sanitized fields the same as they were and ideally preserve whitespace.

Can anyone suggest a good way to do this in MongoDB?

**Update**

The sensitive data is stuff like performance review feedback that has been provided for employees so when testers are using the app they must not see this data. I want to preserve the length of the strings and whitespace so that the the layout of the text is similar to what it is in production.

I was wondering if it would be possible to do this using some simple MongoDB operators, but haven't been able to find what I'm looking for.

The application is written in Java and I am using Spring Data. In the case of MySQL replacing characters with 'x' in the strings in Java and then updating the rows was slow which is why I resorted to using repeat even though I lost the whitespace in the strings.

Comment: Write a loop that iterates thru collection, then for each doc fixes each field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from a MongoDB shell:

```
db.myColl.find().forEach(function(doc){ 
    doc.myField = Array(doc.myField.length+1).join("X"); 
    db.myColl.save(doc); 
});
```

Comment: I had to add a check to see that the field existed for each doc, but this worked.

Comment: You weren't very specific in your question so I provided general answer.

Comment: I wasn't complaining, just mentioning it for future reference. Thanks.